# Scanning an integer using fscanf and delimeter c

Tags: c, scanf

I want to store an `int` to the `correctAnswer` variable in my struct, but it's saved as another type, cause further on I want to compare it with an `int`. How do I modify the following code so that it's saved as an `int` instead?

```
fscanf(file, "%[^;]", &questionArray[i].correctAnswer);
```

It should be something like `"%d[^;]"` I guess.

Also, exactly what data type is saved at `questionArray[i].correctAnswer`?

And about the semicolon, it's because the "correctAnswer" is located in the end of the line.

Comment: `if (fscanf(file, "%d", &questionArray[i].correctAnswer) ==1) Success();`

Comment: Posting sample lines to convert would clarify the usage of the delimiter `';'`.

Comment: `%[^;]` is to store data in the variable until `;` is encounters and type would be `char *` . It doesn't have to do anything with location of `correct Answer` .

Comment: How many fields does each line of the file have. Please append a line of your file in the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

suggest:

```
fscanf(file, "%d;", &questionArray[i].correctAnswer);
```

as that will read the data as an integer and also consume the trailing semicolon ';'

Answer (score 0):

File input is much easier to handle and detect problems with first using `fgets()`.

Read the line with `fgets()` and then parse.

```
// 1: Success - save number in an `int`
// O: Bad format
// EOF: No more data 
int get_answer(FILE *file, int *x) {
  char buffer[100];
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file) == NULL) return EOF;
  if (sscanf(buffer, "%*[^;];%d", x) == 1) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

`"%*[^;]` Read and do not save any character except `;`  At least 1 such character must exist to go to the next step.
`";"`  Read and do not save `';'`
`"%d"`  Read and save an `int`